# What is the difference between "executeFunction" and "runContractFunction" in moralis?

Tags: blockchain, moralis

I have been reading both and find similarities,
which one would you recommend to use?

https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-server/web3-sdk/native#runcontractfunction
https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-server/web3/web3#executefunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"certainly  executeFunction is available for .call and .send web3 methods, but runContractFunction is read-only or .call"

Credits: YNikolasKS#6428

Answer (score 0):

Ahh yes that's true

but additional note that `runContractFunction` isn't exactly `.call` as it is called through the Moralis backend API, but it does function similarly

However, if the view only function is dependent to the address interacting w/ the contracts, the msg.sender will be different therefore it will be better to call `executeFunction` instead

Cheers~